# Flutter: Why doesn't the value change when I use setState?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new in Flutter. I want to change the value using `setState` but it doesn't work.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the value that you want to change is outside the Widget.

Answer (score 0):

According to docs `setState()` defination is

> Calling setState notifies the framework that the internal state of this object has changed in a way that might impact the user interface in this subtree, which causes the framework to schedule a build for this State object.

So if the state of the widget changes you have to call setState to trigger a rebuild of the view and see immediatly the changes implied by the new state.

For example:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
 int _counter = 0;

 void _incrementCounter() {

   setState(() {
  _counter++;
  });
 }
```

so the above`setState()` is called telling the flutter framwork that something has changed , which causes the rerun the build method and the updated part is reflected on the screen.If we change the `_counter` without calling setstate() than the changes wont be reflected.